Como incluir fuentes ttf en un proyecto de Windows Forms y C# para que esté disponible después de crear el instalador
Estoy buscando formas de incluir algunas fuentes ttf a mi proyecto de winforms y c#, buscando encontré que se puede hacer mediante programación, pero lo veo muy poco eficiente porque se debe asignar por cada control la fuente que necesite específicamente ese control y por lo mismo tampoco es posible usarlo con el diseñador, lo que busco es que de mi proyecto terminado se puedan incluir las fuentes que utilicé en el desarrollo. Intente hacer algunas cosas antes como por ejemplo copiar las fuentes de la ruta donde se instala el programa a la ruta de las fuentes del sistema, pero no resultó, no se copiaba nada, entonces ahora se me ocurre crear un script vb o bat que instale mediante la consola en la primera vez que se ejecute la aplicación luego de instalarla. Pero antes de probar estas dos ultimas cosas quisiera saber si existe alguna manera, porque intenté varias cosas, incluso encontré esta Como agregar fuentes de letra a un proyecto de windows forms hecho en Visual Studio a través del lenguaje C#  pregunta donde alguien también hizo lo de incluir la carpeta y que arroja un error, también tuve ese mismo error, en pocas palabras no quiero la solución donde debes asignar la fuente de esta forma
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Font = myFont;
}

porque es poco practico, incluso si recién comienzas tu proyecto, estar agregando el tipo de fuente por cada control, incluso si haces un for para asignar a todos, es lo mismo, si no existe una solución no queda de otra que ver por los scripts para usar la consola del sistema operático o si el empaquetador puede instalar las fuentes al momento de instalar el programa.
Muchas gracias.
P.D.
Me parece increíble y un poco decepcionante que C# no tenga esa manera fácil de incluir solo en una carpeta las fuentes que necesite la aplicación.

Sé que se pueden incrustar recursos en esos programas. Tal vez puedas hacer algo así y extraerlo

@Mateo Si, así lo hice, muchas gracias.

Para cambiar la fuente de toda la aplicación puedes utilizar la función Application.SetDefaultFont la cual debe invocarse antes de Application.Run
Ejemplo
internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
        privateFontCollection.AddFontFile("Darling Coffee.ttf");
        Font UnaFuente = new(privateFontCollection.Families[0], 18f);
        Application.SetDefaultFont(UnaFuente);
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}

En el ejemplo anterior la fuente "Darling Coffee.ttf" se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el ejecutable. Si no está ubicada ahí debes agregar la ruta relativa
Por otro lado, es posible heredar de un control y customizarlo. Supongamos que queremos cambiar la fuente y el color solo a los Label. Creamos una clase que extienda de Label y esa la usamos en el diseñador
internal static class Program
{
    public static Font UnaFuente;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        PrivateFontCollection privateFontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
        privateFontCollection.AddFontFile("Darling Coffee.ttf");
        UnaFuente = new(privateFontCollection.Families[0], 18f);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public CustomLabel()
    {
        this.Font = Program.UnaFuente;
        this.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}


Sin ánimo de polemizar, quiero detenerme en tu último comentario:

Me parece increíble y un poco decepcionante que C# no tenga esa manera
fácil de incluir solo en una carpeta las fuentes que necesite la
aplicación.

Creo que, si hay manera fácil, el código que he puesto me parece fácil. En cualquier caso, tu comentario me parece que es como pedir que una TV de los años 80' soporte HD.
WindowsForms es una tecnología que tiene más de 2 décadas, es sucesora de otra aún más vieja (VB). Es una tecnología que debería morir, pero es presa de su gran éxito. Y para poner en contexto, cuando nació la tecnología era "mal visto" por muchos cambiar el diseño de una app windows, se esperaba que estas app tuvieran una apariencia nativa; era un asunto de usabilidad, los usuarios de ese tiempo no habían nacido con una PC en casa.
Luego aparece WPF, que incluye una UI basada en XAML. Esta tecnología lleva la customización del diseño hasta el límite. Puedes crear y modificar componentes como tu imaginación quiera, tienes templates y "hojas de estilos" similar a lo que son lo CSS (pero en XAML) y aún más poderoso. Es pionera en diseño responsivo, antes que la misma palabra "responsivo" se usara, e incluso existe una herramienta especializada para el diseño Microsoft Blend
De ahí en más todas las nuevas tecnologías de escritorio de Microsoft usan XAML.

UWP
Xamarin
MAUI, esta última incluye la posibilidad de utilizar diseño web (html+css)

En conclusión, cuando se utilizan tecnologías arcaicas siempre hay este tipo de problemas. No necesariamente se debe utilizar la última tecnología, por ejemplo, yo prefiero WPF antes cualquier otra opción, pero hay que ser consientes de las dificultades que pueden aparecer a causa de esta preferencia.

Gracias, como siempre, tus respuestas bien detalladas, contigo siempre aplica el meme de "Nosborn que galán" "Hay algo que este joven no haga bien" jejje. Pues si, la verdad opté por usar las herramientas que ofrece el programa que empaqueta la aplicación y asi ya no hice nada con el código, así lo deje. Pero ahora no sé tengo algunos problemas con el modo release, ya que usé algunas librerías como Bunifu y en modo Debug no tengo ningún tema, pero al intentar sacar el modo release del proyecto me marca que no encuentra los espacios de nombre, sabes a que podría deberse, estoy buscando.

@José Muchas gracias por tus palabras, me alegra haber podido ayudarte, aunque sea un poco. Es increíble como siempre se tienen problemas al publicar, nos pasa a todos. No recuerdo haber tenido tu problema en específico, pero por adivinar, quizás hay archivos dll's que no se están copiando, compara la carpeta debug con la release para ver si encuentras diferencias. Si no es eso, puedes generar una nueva pregunta, así puedes brindar más detalles del error

Pues no sé que habrá pasado, pero como he estado creando respaldos al hacer cambios relevantes al proyecto y separando al final la versión Demo de la original he creado para ello carpetas donde los voy guardando, tanto que moví varias veces de la ubicación original la versión final, presentí que era ese el conflicto que no encuentra la ruta inicial donde fue creado el proyecto, asi que hice unos movimientos y la versión del release la devolví a la ruta original de todo el proyecto, jajaja y parece que ya todo está en orden, ya me estaba volviendo loco porque es ya para sacarla. Gracias

@José qué bueno que hayas podido resolver el problema. Quizás debas plantearte usar GitHub que se acopla muy fácil con visual studio. Antes que existiera GitHub yo usaba simplemente Dropbox con muy buenos resultados, ya que guarda un historial de cambios de los archivos

@ Yussef  GitHub no lo veo confiable en cuestiones de seguridad y privacidad del código, no lo veo como un lugar donde pudiera guardar todo con mucha tranquilidad, estos proyectos son desarrollos como desarrollador independiente y ocasionalmente en colaboración de clientes, por lo que prefiero tener todo local y liberar las aplicaciones hasta luego de hacer todo lo que esté a mi alcance para "proteger" mi trabajo. Muchas gracias Yussef, ojala sigamos saludándonos por aquí gracias a mis novatadas jajaja. Saludos.

Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo @Yussef, para mi C# es el mejor lenguaje del mundo, comence programando en delphi y fui feliz, aprendi c# y me enamore, despues probe java pero que va(ya habia descubierto c#), c# supera con creces a java, c# para mi no tiene rival, los que defienden otro lenguaje es pq nunca han programado en c#, no saben lo que se pierden, no tengo idea del topten de lenguajes de programacion, pero para mi c# se lleva las 10 primeras posiciones, el resto de los lenguajes empiezan a competir a partir de la posicion 11
